# Android: controlling widget margins

Tags: android, android-widget, margins

It's a bit of a frustration that [as of Android 4.0, app widgets are automatically given margins between the widget frame and the app](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy):

[image: Standard Widget Anatomy]

The space on a small phone's screen is at a premium, and the margin can represent quite a large loss, particularly when the widget is small too.  Despite hours of looking, I can't see a way to override or control the widget's margins.

However, I have been playing recently with the [Nova launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en), and note that it's possible to control widget margins using that launcher.  What is more, although there's a global widget margin setting (something like None, Small, Medium, Large), this setting can be activated per widget.

And it's lovely to get widgets that extend from edge to edge.  See, for example, the following screenshot from [my meteogram app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cloud3squared.meteogram):

[image]

So, the question is... how does the Nova launcher control widget margins, and can the same method be used at the widget level, or does the control necessarily come from launcher level so that there is no hope for ever controlling widget margins unless you're a launcher developer?

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are correct.
Widget margin control lies with launcher so there is not much you can do about it unless you build a launcher.